# VBA Access - Checking recordset on subform load

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an `On_Load()` sub which checks the records present on a subform, record by record. For example, if the subform loads with 12 records on it, I need the sub to start with the first record, run a `DCount` (it checks if the job number appears on a different table), then move to the next record, and check that one, etc until it reaches the last record. Here's my code at the moment:

```
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.MoveFirst
'Put code to check keyword schedule here. First get job no
        Do Until Me.Specific_Job_No.Value = "00"
            strSpec = Format(Me.Specific_Job_No.Value, "00")
            strJob = Left(Me.Parent.JobRef.Value, 18) + strSpec
'Then check if that job no is in slot 1, then 2, etc
            If DCount("*", "tblKeywordsSchedule", "[Slot1] Like ""*" & strJob & "*""") > 0 Then
                Me![Added to Schedule] = True
                Me![Added to Schedule].Locked = True
            Else
                Me![Added to Schedule] = False
                Me![Added to Schedule].Locked = False
            End If
'Then go to next record
    rst.MoveNext
        Loop
```

My problem is, it gets stuck on `rst.MoveNext` and just keeps checking the first record over and over again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code has no sense to me. You are doing a loop on a criteria that has nothing to do with your recordset, and inside your loop you don't do something with  any value present in the recordset. What are you trying to achieve ??

Comment: @ThomasG I am trying to loop through twelve records which load in the recordset and do something to them (subject to a DCount).

Comment: the Dount and everything after are performed on value of your from your form (Me!), and not from the recordset. So what is the utility of  looping on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you cannot lock a field individually for each record.

So the `[Added to Schedule]` may change its locking during the loop but will keep the setting of the last record in the loop.

Comment: OK I've removed that line and just kept the update to true or false line. My code now loops through the correct amount of times, but only updates the first line over and over. I feel like the two lines specifying strSpec and strJob are not being updated.

Comment: Like @Thomas G, I can't see you are updating anything. There simply isn't any code that could update.

Answer (score 0):

I have now sorted it out myself. Found TheSmileyCoder's answer on this page:
https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/942501-looping-through-subform-records

I was referring to a form control (Me!) rather than the recordset clone to update the strSpec and strJob strings - that was all I needed to know.

```
If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    With rst
    rst.MoveFirst
        Do While Not .EOF
                strSpec = Format(rst![Specific Job No], "00")
                strJob = Left(Me.Parent.JobRef.Value, 18) + strSpec
'Then check if that job no is in slot 1, then 2, etc
                    If DCount("*", "tblKeywordsSchedule", "[Slot1] Like ""*" & strJob & "*""") > 0 Then
                        .Edit
                        rst![Added to Schedule] = True
                        .Update
                    Else
                        .Edit
                        rst![Added to Schedule] = False
                        .Update
                    End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Just What I said ;)